# Pthread - Thread does not run?

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel-4

My question will be very simple.

First class, which extends the `Thread` class:

```
class FileSender extends Thread {
    private $client;

    public function __construct() {
        // it goes here, since it's called in the main thread
    }

    private function write($buff) {
        File::append(public_path()."/test.log", $buff.PHP_EOL);
    }

    public function run() {
        $this->write("test");
        while (true) {
            $avatar = Pool::getNextAvatar();
            if ($avatar !== null) {
                $this->write("Preparing to send...");
                // bla, bla, bla...
            } else {
                $this->write("No file to send");
                sleep(60);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the caller:

```
$fs = new FileSender();
$fs->start();

while (true) {
    sleep(10);
}
```

The file in `public/test.log` is not populated.
Do you guys know why ?

If I call `run()` it just works fine, but I want it to be fully asynchronous.

## Edit

In fact it's going into the `run()` function but only for a few moment. Writing to a file is quite heavy to do, I think the thread is already killed(?) when the end of the writing comes. But the question is why ?